# Why doesn't make_shared work with Variable Length Arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, shared-ptr, make-shared

consider the following: I have a class A with a constructor which takes an array of ints of size 3 as argument.

Now I want to construct a shared_ptr to A. If I use

`shared_ptr<>(new A (parameter))`

everything is fine.

But if I try using

`make_shared<A>(parameter)`

the compiler gives an error message. This happens only if the parameter-array is declared on the stack AND with a variable as array size (int parameter [n])

The problem disappears when using static arrays (int parameter[3]) or allocating the array on the heap with new.

I mean, this is no serious issue as there are the mentioned workarounds. Still, I would appreciate any explanation on why whis happens...

Btw I'm using g++ 4.8.2.

Here is a minimal example and the error log:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

// some simple class
class A
{
public:
    A () {};
    A (int var[3]) {}; // some non-default constructor with an array as argument
    void foo (){cout << "foo()" << endl;};
};

int main()
{
    // make a shared_ptr to A
    shared_ptr<A> ptr;

    // allocate an array var1 of size nVars=3 on the stack
    int nVars = 3;
    int var1[nVars];
    ptr = shared_ptr<A> (new A(var1)); // without make_shared, the c'tor is recognized
    ptr->foo();
    ptr = make_shared<A> (var1); // <- error at compile time!
    ptr->foo();

    // same with static array var2 of size 3
    int var2[3];
    ptr = make_shared<A> (var2); // <- no compilation error
    ptr->foo();

    // same with dynamic array var3 of size 3
    int* var3 = new int[nVars];
    ptr = make_shared<A> (var3); // <- no compilation error
    ptr->foo();

    return 0;
}
```

build log:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
../main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
../main.cpp:25:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘make_shared(int [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)nVars) + -1)) + 1)])’
  ptr = make_shared<A> (var1); // <- error at compile time!
                            ^
../main.cpp:25:28: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:82:0,
                 from ../main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/shared_ptr.h:610:5: note: template<class _Tp, class ... _Args> std::shared_ptr<_Tp1> std::make_shared(_Args&& ...)
     make_shared(_Args&&... __args)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/shared_ptr.h:610:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
../main.cpp:25:28: note:   variable-sized array type ‘int (&)[(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)nVars) + -1)) + 1)]’ is not a valid template argument
  ptr = make_shared<A> (var1); // <- error at compile time!
                            ^
```

Cheers and thanks in advance for your answers!

Juri

Comment: VLAs don't exist in C++. GCC (and clang I think) have that as an extension.

Comment: Use a vector instead.

Comment: Your "some non-default constructor with an array as argument" really has a pointer as parameter. It is the same as `A (int* var) {};`.

Comment: @Mat Ok thanks! I wasn't aware that the STL doesn't support VLAs.

Comment: `make_shared` perfectly forwards, but VLAs as implemented in GCC/clang cannot be used in template arguments.  Use `+var` to force a decay to pointer - or just don't use VLA.